# How do I "auto-use" all classes from namespaces?

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm using the Doctrine framework, which makes use of namespaces. I would like to keep these namespaces, but avoid having my developers worry about using said namespaces in the files they will be working on.

For example, I have a namespace for Repositories and Entities, which presently need to be access with "Entity\MyEntity" or "Repository\MyRepo". I want these to be accessible instead by "MyEntity" and "MyRepo".

Is there a way to "auto-use" classes from a given namespace (for classes/code that is outside of that namespace)?

Comment: You might be looking for this, but I'm not 100% sure: http://php.net/language.namespaces.importing

Comment: If you want to use the 'bare' classname while _not_ being in that namespace: not possible without defining a `use` for every single one of them.